# Javascript Cookies being reset after page reload

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

Good day.
I've been using [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) to set cookies in my application, they are set in the exact same way however one of them turns into undefined whenever i use window.location or reload the page. I set 2 cookies, one for a token and one for for the user role in my application but for whatever reason the user role cookie is reset.

Here is how i set it:

```
login ({dispatch }, payload) {
  axios.get('/login',{
    auth: {
      username: payload.username,
      password: payload.password
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    let in120Minutes = 1/12;
    
    Cookies.set('user_role', response.data['permissions'].user_role, {expires: in120Minutes})
    Cookies.set('token', response.data['x-access-token'], {expires: in120Minutes})
    window.location.pathname = '/myPage'

  }).catch(function (error) {
    dispatch('errorHandler', error, { root: true })
  })
},
```

Why does this happen exactly? I do the exact same thing into another application and it works fine.

Comment: Any pointer you got ?